What would happen to the sky colour if SO2 made up 95% of the atmosphere?
Taking into account the Rayleigh scattering phenomenon, assuming that the atmosphere is 1 bar, how would the light from the G2V-type star interact with this kind of environment? Could the colour of the sky even alter despite the fact that there is a significant amount of sulfur dioxide in the atmosphere? And if so, how would this effect the appearance of auroras and cloud formation?

Welcome to Astronomy! We're nicer than Worldbuilding :-)As mentioned in that other question, Rayleigh scattering is ubiquitous. But the presence of H2O and of dust will have a huge impact, as will therefore temperature and pressure. So I think some significant additional information is needed. An atmosphere and its optical phenomena are complicated, and can't be described simply by shining a certain spectrum of light through a cell of a pure gas. cf. haze and smog.

You may find these Astronomy SE questions and their answers interesting: What color is the Sky on other Planets? and Venus Atmosphere Color and Terrestrial Exoplanet Skies – I've Built a Visual Sky Chart. Is it Accurate? and possibly in Space SE: Why would Mars' sky appear blue at dawn and dusk, but red during the middle of the day (reverse of Earth)?

@uhoh Do you think I should edit this?
Is this better?
"While Rayleigh scattering is a common phenomenon, hence the blue sky on Earth, its effects would be overshadowed by the amount of H2O (water vapor) and dust in the atmosphere, which makes a significant role to the sky appearance and hue. I don't know if this significant amount of sulfur dioxide may effect the appearance of auroras and cloud colour, so a response from you guys would be helpful."

The hard part here is that to get a conclusive answer as to the appearance of an atmosphere, you really need to build and model it. How much dust? How much fog and smog? etc. Also, auroras and clouds and sky are three different phenomena and really need to be asked in completely separate questions. I recommend you add some more specifics, then ask a single, specific question about only one aspect, be it sky (on a clear day) or clouds, or aurora. Choose one for this question, then consider separate questions for the other two.
